# I’m trying to please to the calling

Tags: meaning, lyrics

Van Morrison’s song Moondance has these lines

“And I'm trying to please to the calling / Of your heart-strings that play soft and low.”

What are we to make of “please to the calling” -- an intransitive “please” followed not by an infinitive but by a prepositional “to.”

Is it one of those obsolete Scottish uses that OED lists for “please”?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's lyrics interpretation

Comment: I think it's saying he's trying to please the heart-strings. Written another way: The heart-strings are playing soft and low, calling out to the singer, and the singer is trying to please them.

Comment: Or maybe just “I’m trying to please [you, and I’m doing so] to the calling of your heart-strings.” 

Too bad. I was hoping there was a lesson here about some obsolete construction of intransitive “please.” 

Seems to be nothing of the sort.

Comment: I still don't understand why a question about what a particular phrase in a song lyric means should be viewed as inherently off-topic. If someone asks what a phrase in a sentence from an essay means, we don't reflexively argue that the questioner is seeking "essay interpretation" and try to close it. I think that many questions involving phrases found in lyrics—including perhaps this one—can be answered analytically with regard to the sense or structure of the wording, without embarking on a flight of fancy, and that they are therefore valid questions to ask at this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> And I'm trying to **please to** the calling
>   Of your heart-strings that play soft and low

The poetry of the lyrics juxtaposes "please" and "to," and you might be tempted to think that "please to" is idiomatic.  But it means

> [As an accompaniment] **to** your heart-strings, I'm trying to **please**
>   [you].

In other words

> I'm trying to accommodate the subtle romantic signals that you're
>   sending me.

Try working *that* into a love song.

Comment: Yes, I was indeed looking for a “please to” idiom. I think you are right,  though I’d lean toward "respond to” and “response” instead of “accommodate” and “accompaniment” to draw in the “calling”: “I am trying to please you, in response to the call of your heart-strings.” Thanks. Up vote. Answered.